# Use Apple keyboard command key in Fedora-like system with MWM

Tags: linux, xorg

**I want to be able to `CMD-TAB` between windows using an Apple keyboard on a Fedora-like system using MWM.**

- The OS is an in-house distro, not a standard Fedora distribution.
- Pressing `ALT-TAB` currently switches to the next window
- I have re-mapped the left `CMD` key to `ALT`:

  - `xev` shows that the `CMD` key is keycode 115
  - my `~/.Xmodmap` file has the following line:

    ```
    keycode 115 = Alt_L
    ```
  - When I run `xev` and press the left `CMD` key, I get the following output:

    ```
    KeyPress event, serial 24, synthetic NO, window 0xc00001,
        root 0x1b6, subw 0x0, time 614726707, (698, 1524), root: (721, 1547),
        state 0x0, keycode 115 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
        XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 64
        XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
        XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
        XFilterEvent returns: False
    ```

However when I press `CMD-TAB` nothing happens.  What am I missing?